# how to use underscore with out math symbol

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, underscore

I am just what want to define a tcolorbox with title box environment like this：
[I:OBJ_ID_123]
due to it is contains underscore.it is very tedious to type_ to show underscore everytime.because my documents contains so many fixed format like  I:OBJ_ID_123 .how to make a format just type as plain text without using math symbol mode.just type as [I:OBJ_ID_123].for example

this is demo:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign title=flush right,title=\texttt{[I:OBJ\_ID\_123] }]
        this is demo for how to define this,i need this effect
    \end{tcolorbox}
% start new effect, begin ID:124,125......, it is very hard to type \_ to escape underscore
    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign title=flush right,title=\texttt{[I:OBJ\_ID\_124] }]
    so the second ID begin 124, i need to type [I:OBJ\_ID\_124]
    how to directly to type[I:OBJ_ID_124]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can define a `\newcommand`.

Comment: Please let us understand your problem and post some minimal working code. Thanks

Comment: has updated the question.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only the digits will change, here's a way to do it by defining a new command `\obj`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\obj}[1]{I:OBJ\_ID\_#1}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign title=flush right,title=\texttt{[I:OBJ\_ID\_123] }]
        this is demo for how to define this,i need this effect
    \end{tcolorbox}
% start new effect, begin ID:124,125......, it is very hard to type \_ to escape underscore
    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign title=flush right,title=\texttt{[I:OBJ\_ID\_124] }]
    so the second ID begin 124, i need to type [I:OBJ\_ID\_124]
%    how to directly to type[I:OBJ_ID_124]
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign title=flush right,title=\texttt{[\obj{456}] }]
        using a macro (newcommand) to insert the digits
    \end{tcolorbox}
       
\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]

For more details on `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment` see here, e.g. to absorb the title and tcolorbox statements: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros .